# When creating Angular 2 library npm package, should I use peerDependencies or dependencies for Angular 2 dependencies?

Tags: angular, npm

Currently, when I create npm package for Angular 2, mainly as Angular 2 services, I use `peerDependencies` as follow:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.6"
  }
```

I don't use `dependencies` because I don't want my package to pull them during `npm install`. As I expect the target application is Angular 2.

And put all dependencies needed to compile my package in `devDependencies`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.6",
    "typescript": "*",
    "typings": "*"
  }
```

However, should I use `dependencies` or `peerDependencies`?

My main concern is for application using the package. Do they affect the build process of the consuming application?

Or am I doing it plain wrong and should switch back to `dependencies`?

Comment: You are doing it right. `peerDependencies` is the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

> Peer Dependencies
>
> What we need is a way of expressing these "dependencies" between
>   plugins and their host package. Some way of saying, "I only work when
>   plugged in to version 1.2.x of my host package, so if you install me,
>   be sure that it's alongside a compatible host." We call this
>   relationship a peer dependency.

As I interpret it, peer dependencies are simply to tell the one who's using your package that it won't work if they do not install the peer dependencies.